# How to rewrite this URL to a redirect page?

Tags: coldfusion, url-rewriting

I am using Microsoft-IIS/7.5 on a hosted server (Hostek.com)

I have an existing site with 2,820 indexed links in Google.  You can see the results by searching Google with this: site:flyingpiston.com  Most of the pages use a section, makerid, or bikeid to get the right information. Most of the links look like this:

```
flyingpiston.com/?BikeID=1068
flyingpiston.com/?MakerID=1441
flyingpiston.com/?Section=Maker&MakerID=1441
flyingpiston.com/?Section=Bike&BikeID=1234
```

On the new site, I am doing URL rewriting using .htaccess. The new URLs will look like this:

```
flyingpiston.com/bike/1068/
flyingpiston.com/maker/1123/
```

Basically, I just want to use my htaccess file to direct any request with a "?" question mark in it directly a coldfusion page called redirect.cfm.  On this page, I will use ColdFusion to write a custom 301 redirect. Here's what ColdFusion's redirect looks like:

```
<cfheader statuscode="301" statustext="Moved Permanently">
<cfheader name="Location" value="http://www.newurl/bike/1233/">
<cfabort>
```

So, what does my htaccess file need to look like if I want to push everything with a question mark to a particular page? Here's what I have tried, but it's not working.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^? /redirect.cfm [NS,L]
```

Update. Using the advice from below, I am using this rule:

```
RewriteRule \? /redirect/redirect.cfm [NS,L]
```

To try to push this request

```
http://flyingpiston2012-com.securec37.ezhostingserver.com/?bikeid=1235
```

To this page:

```
http://flyingpiston2012-com.securec37.ezhostingserver.com/redirect/redirect.cfm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of reasons what you're trying isn't working.

The first one is that RewriteRule uses a regex, and `?` is a regex metacharacter, which therefore needs be escaped with a backslash (`\?`) to tell it to match the literal question mark character.

However, the second part of the problem is that the regex for [**RewriteRule**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) is only tested against the filename part of the URL - it **specifically excludes the query string**.

In order to match against the query string you need to use the [**RewriteCond**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) directive, placed on the line before the rule (but applied *in between* the RewriteRule matching and replacing), acting as an additional filter. The useful bit is that you can specify which part of the URL to match against (as well as having the option for using non-regex tests).

Bearing all this in mind, **the simplest way** to match/rewrite a request with a query string is:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule .* /redirect/redirect.cfm
```

The `%{QUERY_STRING}` is what the regex is tested against (everything in CF's CGI scope can be used here, and some other stuff too - see [the Server Variables box](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) in the docs).

The single `.` just says "make sure the matched item has any single character"

At the moment, this rule will preserve the existing query string - if you want to discard it, you can place a `?` onto the end of the replacement URL. (If you need to use a query string on the URL and *not* discard the old version, use the `[QSA]` flag.)

In the opposite direction, you're losing the filename part of the URL - to preserve this, you probably want to append it onto the replacement as PATH_INFO, using the automatic whole-match capture `$0`.

These two things together provides:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule .* /redirect/redirect.cfm/$0?
```

One final thing is that you'll want to guard against infinite loops - the above rule strips the query string so it will always fail the RewriteCond, but better to be safe (especially if you might need to add a query string), which you can do with an extra RewriteCond:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/redirect/redirect\.cfm
RewriteRule .* /redirect/redirect.cfm/$0?
```

Multiple RewriteCond are combined as ANDs, and the `!` negates the match.

You can of course add whatever flags are required to the RewriteRule to have it behave as desired.

Comment: Yes, there is a reason I need ColdFusion to do it.  I actually need to append additional information to the new URL.  newurl/maker/1234/ needs to become newurl/maker/1234/west-coast-choppers I need to pull the "west-coast-choppers" from the database.

Comment: Fair enough. That's actually possible with Apache (with [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap)) but almost certainly easier with CF.

Comment: I don't have access to anything other than the .htaccess file. So, I will have tons of control using ColdFusion.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: In what way? Are you getting any errors, or is it just not going over to CF?  (Check Apache's error log). Two general debug things you can try - change the match to `.*` to match everything (i.e. `RewriteRule .* /redirect/redirect.cfm [NS,L]`) whch helps identify if the rule is firing, also try a temp redirect to a non-CF page to see if there's ny issue there (i.e. `RewriteRule \? /test.html [NS,L,R=302]`)

Comment: Again, this is on a hosted server so I can't check the Apache error logs. Yes, this rule moves ALL traffic to the redirect.cfm page (RewriteRule .* /redirect/redirect.cfm [NS,L]) No modifications seem to work though.

Comment: A decent host should still give you access to logs relating to your domain (might be in some obscure option in a control panel though). Anyhow, if `.*` works try `.*\?` and if that works `[^?]*\?` is a more efficient way to write it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19314/discussion-between-evik-james-and-peter-boughton)

Comment: Peter, thanks for your help.  My host had me add this to the bottom of my rules. It works, although I really don't know why nothing else worked.  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule (.*) /redirect/redirect.cfm$1? [NC,NS,R=301,L]

Comment: Hey Evik, I just went and re-read the relevant docs, and the simple answer is you can't match the query string in the RewriteRule - you need the RewriteCond (as your host provided). Can't believe I've used it so long without encountering that before! :( Anyhow, I'll go update the answer with the working rule and some relevant details.

Comment: Ok, answer updated. Note that you can use just `.` instead of `.+` for the RewriteCond, also `.*` with `$0` (instead of `(.*)` with `$1`), plus an extra RewriteCond that might be a good idea. Hopefully all makes sense - let me know if any part needs clarifying?

Comment: Peter, thanks for your help. No, it doesn't make much sense. I rarely work with regular expressions and I have no access to logs, so I really can't see what's going on or do much experimenting.  You have been a big help though. Thanks so much!

Comment: Actually, I commented above before I read your updated answer. I will read that now.