# How to rewrite a URL to match ANY BikeID (specific phrase)?

Tags: apache, coldfusion, url-rewriting

I am using ColdFusion 10 on a hosted server (hostek.com).

I am trying to write a rewrite rule so that any URL with a BikeID will get redirected to a specific page. I have this as the first rule on the page. The other rules I have are working just fine.

Here is my rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^bikeid* /redirect/redirect.cfm [NC,NS,L]
```

This rule works for this URL

```
http://flyingpiston2012-com.securec37.ezhostingserver.com/bikeid=2069
```

This rule does NOT work for this URL

```
http://flyingpiston2012-com.securec37.ezhostingserver.com/?bikeid=2069
```

Other rules that I have tried that do not work are as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^bikeid* /redirect/redirect.cfm [NC,NS,L]
RewriteRule ^*bikeid* /redirect/redirect.cfm [NC,NS,L]
RewriteRule *bikeid* /redirect/redirect.cfm [NC,NS,L]
RewriteRule \?*bikeid* /redirect/redirect.cfm [NC,NS,L]
RewriteRule ^\?*bikeid* /redirect/redirect.cfm [NC,NS,L]
RewriteRule ^\?bikeid* /redirect/redirect.cfm [NC,NS,L]
```

What do I have to put in the rule to match any URL that contains the phrase "bikeid"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My host (hostek.com) FINALLY got back to me and provided me with an answer. I really don't know how it works, as their explanation was totally lacking. It does work though. They instructed me to add this to the botom of my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule (.*) /redirect/redirect.cfm$1? [NC,NS,L]
```

Comment: I've written up an explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13290778/how-to-rewrite-this-url-to-a-redirect-page#13291774) - hopefully all makes sense. Note the NC flag isn't needed - it stands for nocase but the pattern is already case insensitive.